# Create Solr core in console with authentication

Tags: solr, console

I have a Solr core that needs an authentication. Let's say I have a `user` with password `password`.
When I now try to create a Solr core in the console with

`bin\solr create -c test`

I get an HTTP Error 401.
Of course I need to specify my user. How can I add my user and password in the console?
Something like `bin\solr create -c test -authentication user:password`

Answer (score 6):

Using Command Line scripts with BasicAuth
Add the following line to the (/opt/solr/bin) solr.in.sh or solr.in.cmd file. This example tells the bin/solr command line to to use "basic" as the type of authentication, and to pass credentials with the user-name "solr" and password "SolrRocks":

`SOLR_AUTH_TYPE="basic"
SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-Dbasicauth=solr:SolrRocks"`

look: 
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/basic-authentication-plugin.html#BasicAuthenticationPlugin-UsingBasicAuthwithSolrJ

Comment: In Ubuntu, the default path to configure these lines is `/etc/default/solr.in.sh`

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Basic Authentication](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/basic-authentication-plugin.html#BasicAuthenticationPlugin-EditingAuthenticationPluginConfiguration) than first set in the CMD Console:

```
set SOLR_AUTH_TYPE=basic
set SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-Dbasicauth=USER:PASS"
```

Customize USER:PASS for your need

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while so, I am not sure if you still have this issue. But this can help others who may come across this like how I did.

I am new to solr, so there could be a better way of doing this than what I have here.

Are you using zookeeper for authentication?

Assuming you are using zookeeper for authentication

First of all, I checked and I don't think there is an -authentication parameter for solr create command. 
So, this is how I hacked around this issue:

1. Stopped solr
2. Started solr without zookeeper
3. created the core like how you tried for the test core
4. Then uploaded configuration of the test core to zookeeper. I followed this document - https://systemsarchitect.net/2013/04/06/painless-guide-to-solr-cloud-configuration/
5. Restarted zookeeper server
6. Started solr with -p 8983 -z zookeeper_hostname:zookeeper_port
   You should be able to access your test core with authentication enabled